# 100% height in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

```
#loading {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

in ie >= 7 it’s works perfectly, but in ie6 height equal line height

Answer (score 3):

Is it a block you want to fill the window? Then you have to set the height of the html and body tag too.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```